# Need Guidance with writing MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'll admit, up front, that this is my first MySQL trigger. The MySQL version is 8.0.

I have a table for orders and order line items. In the orders table I have a column that stores the total of all line items. I need a trigger that updates that total every time a line items is added or changed for that order. Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_line_item_total
AFTER INSERT
   ON orderlines.price FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- variable declarations
   DECLARE li_order_id INT;
   DECLARE li_total DEC;

   SET li_order_id = orderlines.order_id; 
   SET li_total = SUM (orderlines.price) WHERE orderlines.order_id = li_order_id;

   -- trigger code
   UPDATE orders SET 
    total_lineitems = li_total
    WHERE orders.order_id = li_order_id;
END;
```

I put this into MySQL Workbench and it was rejected. I know that the DECLARE statements, the 2nd SET statement, and the END statements were the ones flagged as incorrect, however I'm not even sure where to look to find out what's wrong.

Looking for guidance and direction.

### Thanks,

Michael Frankel
Wizard Consulting Group, Inc.

Comment: Stop and just **don't**. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So writing sum over one table into another isn't a good thing to do. If you need the sum, you can always query it and get the **right** result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your problem is on this line :  `SET li_total = SUM (orderlines.price) WHERE orderlines.order_id = li_order_id;`
2. add delimiters.

do this :

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER update_line_item_total
AFTER INSERT
   ON orderlines.price FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- variable declarations
   DECLARE li_order_id INT;
   DECLARE li_total DEC;
   declare li_total_temp dec;

   SET li_order_id = orderlines.order_id; 
   select orderlines.price into li_total_temp  WHERE orderlines.order_id = li_order_id;
   SET li_total =  li_total + li_total_temp;

   -- trigger code
   UPDATE orders SET 
    total_lineitems = li_total
    WHERE orders.order_id = li_order_id;
END |
delimiter ;
```